# error: the `?` operator is not stable error when installing cargo-update

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to update cargo: `cargo install cargo-update`, but I'm faced with the following error:

```
   Compiling semver-parser v0.7.0
error: the `?` operator is not stable (see issue #31436)
  --> /home/netlab/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/semver-parser-0.7.0/src/version.rs:56:26
   |
56 |     let (pre, pre_len) = common::parse_optional_meta(&s[i..], b'-')?;
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: the `?` operator is not stable (see issue #31436)
  --> /home/netlab/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/semver-parser-0.7.0/src/version.rs:58:30
   |
58 |     let (build, build_len) = common::parse_optional_meta(&s[i..], b'+')?;
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: the `?` operator is not stable (see issue #31436)
   --> /home/netlab/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/semver-parser-0.7.0/src/range.rs:133:26
    |
133 |     let (pre, pre_len) = common::parse_optional_meta(&s[i..], b'-')?;
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: *I am trying to update cargo: `cargo install cargo-update`* — This is **not** how you update cargo. This installs a cargo subcommand called `cargo-update`. You update cargo itself by the same mechanism that you installed it originally (rustup or your system package manager, whichever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your Rust version — with [versions of Rust before 1.13](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/11/10/Rust-1.13.html) you will receive the error because the operator wasn't stable in these versions.

Your error message refers to [a GitHub issue number](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31436).